# Holiday Request Approval, updating secondary list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

I have created a holiday request approval process, but what I am looking to do now is update a second list that has information such as holiday allowance and days remaining on.

The example scenario, I put in a holiday request for 2 days and I have 22 days altogether. Once this request gets approved, I want the second list to update to give me -2 days and give me 20 remaining days.

So, next time i request a holiday, it will tell me i have 20 days left and not 22. Does this make sense? Any help will be appreciated :)

I am currently using SharePoint 2013, will be upgrading to 365 next year. I am using SharePoint Designer for my workflows as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by having 2 columns in the second list: total number of days allowed in a year (22) and days remaining (20). Optionally, you could also store the vacation activity log in a text field for audit purposes.

When a user submits the vacation request in the first list and the approval takes place, you can update the item in the second list using a workflow that runs with elevated permissions as you most likely don't want the user submitting the request to update second list. I hope it helps get you started.